# failure to close UI debuggers in Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

We are using testng with selenium.  We can use IE, Firefox or Chrome but almost always use Chrome.  At the beginning of each test, a driver instance is obtained (as shown below) depending on the browser.  This has been working fine but lately, and then just once, one test failed with the error message "**org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception
from unknown error: failed to close UI debuggers**"  I did some searches in Google and other people had similar problems but I did not see a lot of resolution.  My guess is that it was some temporary technical glitch or network problem.  But I am curious whether anyone has gotten this error, and moreover what it might mean?  Not sure whether it helps, but it was developed on Eclipse, and a jar created (with a bat file to execute the tests).  The tests were being run from this jar file and only one failed, and only once.

```
        // capabilities for different browsers.
        extraCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, seleniumProxyObject);
        extraCapabilities.setCapability("ie.setProxyByServer", true);
        extraCapabilities.setCapability("ie.usePerProcessProxy", true);
        extraCapabilities.setCapability("download.default_directory", System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
        // create driver with additional capabilities
        webDriver = DriverFactory.getDriverInstance(driver, browser, extraCapabilities);
```

Comment: try to make sure all instances of chrome are closed before running the test. You can also try to run chrome with disabled dev tools (`—disable-dev-tools`)

Comment: Thanks @KirilS. closing chrome worked :)